# Filter a nested collection and return main object using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following two classes (DB objects):

```
class Person
{
    public int Id;
    public List<Car> CarsOwned;
}

class Car
{
    public string Name;
}
```

I want to be able to search for a person with Id 1 and return all the cars with names ford & ferrari that the person owns. I want the person object returned.

What I have so far:

```
List<string> carsFilter = new List<string>();
carsFilter.Add("Ford");
carsFilter.Add("Ferrari");

person.Where(x => x.Id == 1).CarsOwned.Where(y => carsFilter.Contains(y.Name));
```

How do I return the person object instead of the Cars object? (Person is an IQueryable and I would like the query to be done in one DB transaction if possible)

Comment: Your question is a little confusing because you state that you want to return 2 different things: *"I want to...return **all the cars** with names ford & ferrari that the person owns. I want the **person object** returned"*. Do you want to return all the cars or the person? It sounds like you want the person, but it's easy for us to assume that the `Id` field is unique, in which case you're only ever going to get one person anyway.

Comment: Yuriy has the right idea but a small syntax mistake, also without any kind of explanation I'd rather put his correction here as a comment rather than editing his answer. Try `person.Where(x => x.Id == 1 && x.CarsOwned.Any(c => carsFilter.Contains(y.Name)));`.

Comment: @RufusL I want to return the person object but I want to the CardOwned filtered so that it only contains cars with name ferrari & ford.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL shouldn't that be `c.Name`?

Comment: @RufusL You have corrected the corrector! Indeed it should be `person.Where(x => x.Id == 1 && x.CarsOwned.Any(c => carsFilter.Contains(c.Name)));`

Answer (score 3):

```
person.Where(x => x.Id == 1 && CarsOwned.Any(c => carsFilter.Contains(y.Name)));
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add two conditions, one for the id and another one for the cars. Now, you have a list with all the cars the person should own. Using the combination of `All` and `Any` extension methods you can find those persons whose have all the cars in the `carsFilter` collection:

```
var result=persons.Where(p => p.Id == 1 && carsFilter.All(c=>p.CarsOwned.Any(e => e.Name==c));
```